# Rails: Expected.. To Define Account_number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails project and keep getting the following error when trying to load my new.html.erb page:

```
Expected /usr/local/www/apache22/data/update_pi_names/app/models/account_number.rb to define Account_number
```

Heres my def new in the controller:

```
 def new
    @pi_name = PiName.new
    @account_numbers = Account_number.find_all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @pi_name }
    end
  end
```

And my model/account_number.rb:

```
class AccountNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_and_belongs_to_many :pi_names


end
```

Let me know if you need any more info!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reference your model via `AccountNumber` not `Account_number`, hence:

`@account_numbers = AccountNumber.all`

Also, you can use `all` instead of `find_all`

Answer (score 0):

U should write model class name
AccountNumber

```
@account_numbers = AccountNumber.find_all
```

not Account_number

with camel style